# Adding date/time information on video for ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am using FFmpeg for live streaming with RTMP to YouTube.
My ffmpeg command is like this:

```
ffmpeg -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 -f v4l2 -codec:v h264 -framerate 30 \
  -video_size 1920x1080 -itsoffset 0.5 -i /dev/video2 -copyinkf -codec:v copy -codec:a aac \
  -ab 44k -af 'highpass=200, lowpass=3000, volume=1' -g 4 -f flv \
   rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/8b35-vkye-476f-xxxx
```

I want to add date and time information on live stream video.
How can I do this?

Comment: My camera is H.264 camera

Comment: Can I add time-stamp H.264 stream from camera ?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding:

```
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: text='%{localtime\:%T}': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=700"
```

should work. See [Adding time stamp overlay to video stream using ffmpeg](https://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/)

Comment: I did, but does not work properly.

Comment: I think that is why the frame format from camera is H.264 format. so, it can not rendering to H.264 directly.

Comment: Worked for me. I just needed to adjust the coordinates.

Comment: The [Text Expansion section](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Text-expansion) explains how [strftime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) is used so you can replace `%T` with any strftime format